# GNU Screen in XTerm resets cursor shape

Tags: gnu-screen, xterm

In my `.bashrc` I use `printf -- '\x1b[6 q'` to get blinking bar cursor in my `xterm(1)`s. When I run `screen(1)` then it resets the cursor to non-blinking block and also seems to be ignoring all variants of the cursor shape control sequences I am trying.

The solution would be either to prohibit the `screen(1)` from reseting the cursor shape or to make it interpret (pass-through to the underlaying terminal) the cursor control sequence(s). Is either of these options possible? Thank you.

OT: `tmux(1)` is OK and does not change the cursor shape at start, by the way...

---

One possible solution is to place the setting of the cursor shape
in the GNU `readline(3)` configuration file.

In the `.inputrc` file:

```sh
$if mode=emacs
    $if term=screen.xterm
        set show-mode-in-prompt on
        # bar cursor
        set emacs-mode-string \1\eP\e[6\ q\e\\\2
    $endif
$endif
```

Alternatively, for the `vi(1)` editing mode use this:

```sh
$if mode=vi
    $if term=screen.xterm
        set show-mode-in-prompt on
        # block cursor in command mode
        set vi-cmd-mode-string \1\eP\e[2\ q\e\\\2
        # bar cursor in insert mode
        set vi-ins-mode-string \1\eP\e[6\ q\e\\\2
    $endif
$endif
```

Now it works as expected and there is also no need to force the blinking in XTerm but only `true` is sufficient to enable it.

The `$if term=screen.xterm`'s will match all XTerm kinds (i.e. `screen.xterm-256colors` will match), because GNU `readline(3)` matches so in case of the `term` special keyword. So, having the initial setup in `.bashrc` like the following, XTerm resource to turn of blinking in `.Xresources` (or `.Xdefaults`) and the above `readline(3)` settings we can achieve the expected behaviour. It's not ideal but it seems to be working. Any improvement is welcome.

In the `.bashrc`:

```bash
case "$TERM" in
    xterm*)
        printf -- '\x1b[6 q'
        ;;
esac
```

In the `.Xresources`:

```yaml
XTerm*vt100*cursorBlink: true
```

It's a bit clunky and I think there might be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure xterm to blink the cursor and ignore any escape sequences to change it later, see `man xterm`. For example, start an xterm with

```sh
xterm -xrm XTerm.vt100.cursorBlink:always
```

Depending on your setup, you can put the resource in a `~/.Xdefaults` file, or `~/.Xresources`, or enter it into the X11 server resource database at startup with, for example,

```sh
echo 'XTerm.vt100.cursorBlink:always' | xrdb -merge
```

Comment: Of course, that forces the blinking cursor (and it works as expected) but it does not prohibit the `screen(1)` from changing the cursor shape which is the most crutial for me. So this solves only half of the problem...

Answer (score 0):

The working solution can be seen in the additional information in the question (under the line). Although it is probably not the best solution of all it does work and does solve the original issue very well. Therefor I close this question as solved providing here just a brief summary of the solution: (1) set cursor shape on shell start in shell configuration, (2) set mode prompt to set the cursor shape as well in GNU readline configuration and (3) set blinking cursor X resource for XTerm (if you need it). The rest is pretty self-explanatory and can be seen from the referenced question part (under the line).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).